# JSP: let the user choose where to download file

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I want to let the user choose where to save a file

Let's say I have a JSP file called "myJSP.jsp" contains a form with one input, the form's action refers to a servlet called "MyServlet", this servlet downloads a specific file to the users machine.

The problem is that I can't let the user decide where to download the file!!!

If there is a way to let the user chose the path where he wants to download the file? and it will be passed to the servlet in the HttpRequest

Comment: AFAIK, that's not possible. If the user configures his/her browser to automatically store downloads in a Downloads directory, then that's what the browser will (and should) do.

Comment: @JBNizet I understand that but is there something like <input type='file'> or something like a browse window

Comment: Just as I said, AFAIK, **that's not possible**.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you :)